# cassandra-cli and setting an Integer row key - getting syntax error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I created a cassandra column family that looks like the following:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY foo 
 WITH comparator= UTF8Type 
 AND key_validation_class=IntegerType
 AND column_metadata=[{column_name: bar_user_key, validation_class: UTF8Type}];
```

Attempting to create a new column with a value, I'm seeing the following syntax error:

```
[default@mykeyspace] SET foo[23]["Bar:12/User:15"] = "1";
Syntax error at position 31: unexpected """ for `SET foo[23]["Bar:12/User:15"] = "1";`.
```

Not sure what is going on here. Using Cassandra 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use single quotes with cassandra-cli.

```
SET foo[23]['Bar:12/User:15'] = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes is not allowed use only single quotes

```
SET foo[23]['Bar:12/User:15'] = 1;
```